# Change Background Color of whole datagrid row upon selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, styles

I'm currently building up a WPF Window holding a table using the DataGrid. Binding and updates work fine, I'm also quite contempt with the styling, but I ran into troubles when it comes to selection. This are the prerequisites:

- Table is ReadOnly
- Whole Row Selection

This is the source code for my table: (Yes, I know I did set the selection color 3 times, once for DataGrid, once for the row, once for the cell. I thought maybe one of those would be helping, but it's not the case.)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgv" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="8" RowHeight="32" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HeadersVisibility="Column" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="True"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              LoadingRow="dgv_LoadingRow"
              >
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="center"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Style>
```

It then continues to Column- and RowDefinitions ...

I run into the following problems:

- Only the cells get selected, not the whole line. The margins in the Cells make it look quite weird (See Screenshot)
- The row doesn't select when I click on a margin of a cell (the areas in the Screenshot that are not rendered in red) - makes selecting rows quite unintuitive...
- The cell that I click on to select the row still gets hihglighted (notice the black border around "Peter Müller" in the selected row)

Here's a screenshot of the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Well I guess since nobody came up with anything different I'll have to use the programmatic approach and react to the selectionChanged Event...

Answer (score 1):

What if you were to remove the margin in the cell definition?  That is accounting for the cells taking up extra space and the red not covering that space.  If you removed the margin, do you get what you are looking for.  I think the real answer may be in the `DataGrid.RowBackground` [Property][1].

Property Value
Type: System.Windows.Media.Brush
The brush that paints the background of a row. The registered default is null. For more information about what can influence the value, see DependencyProperty.

You could use a trigger on the IsSelected state to set the color.  By default the entire row of a DataGrid is selected.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Margin="12,12,0,0">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This doesn’t work because the control template of the DataGridRow changes the background of an Border that is internal to the template, not the background of the DataGridRow itself... [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx]

Comment: Thats strange ... I'm getting the same result now. Still, your approach is not working, unfortunatelly it's not even switching the 'selection' color NOR the background color. Basicly as if this piece of code is not being interpreted for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to change default background row selection. you need to
1) edit datagridrow style & template (i.e http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) 
2) handle selectionchanged event and changed background of row.
3) or on datagrid row loaded event get the childrenoftype rectangle equal to "BackgroundRectangle" and set color you want - so using this it effects to all the rows in a datagrid, it is similar to 1 but doing this in code behind.

hope this gives you some idea.